# Mimic special midi reverb event that gets quieter the higher it is set to

Tags: theory, technique, midi, software, reverb

I am looking for a way to play midis with a special reverb in a midi player or similar.

This reverb, which was used in a Nintendo 64 game, uses a special reverb technique that seems to be a combination of hall and reverb and conflicts with each other, resulting in a lower volume the higher the reverb event is set.

Here is an example. First note has no reverb event, second has one with a value of 70, then 90, 100 and 127. It gets steadily quieter even though the actual volume of the channels and notes are completely the same in the midi:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502388312850300928/1092056255528435742/Reverb.mp3

The thing is, it doesn't have to be mimicked completely exactly, I'm just concerned about the volume being mimicked that way.

Answer (score 9):

The reverb doesn't change. That's just the wet/dry balance changing. First is entirely dry [100% signal, 0% reverb], last is entirely wet [0% signal, 100% reverb].
The reverb itself I'd call a relatively un-spectacular room emulation, available anywhere. You might have to bit-filter it to get it as grainy as the original.

There is no dedicated controller message for wet/dry, though there are many controllers that *could* be used, all just labelled 'generic'. A manufacturer may be using any of thse, or even NRPNs. [non-registered parameter numbers]. You could possibly identify it if you have the actual midi file.

Here's an easy-to read list of controllers - [Another Producer](https://anotherproducer.com/online-tools-for-musicians/midi-cc-list/)
Full [mind-numbing] detail is available from https://www.midi.org/

Comment: I'd suggest using a fast delay in addition to a short reverb to get the graininess.

Comment: That will generate 'flutter' not grain. The graininess comes from the low bit-rate of the effect. I didn't address the awful 'clanginess'… but I'm sure you could find some point on even a decent reverb that would emulate your grandma's dining room ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was using the word "grain" in the same sense as granular synthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But with which midi editor or player could you set this reverb, or mimic? With VLC Player, for example, I can configure a reverb with the Spatializer, but this is then fixed to all channels and uses only a single fixed reverb value, instead of that it is oriented to the reverb midi event.
I have also experimented with LMMS, mimicking the reverb, but the program seems to use a completely different volume level, causing the volume levels of the individual instruments to be quite different.

Comment: It look like you should be able to do it in LMMS, but I've never tried it, so I really don't know how it works beyond what the first page of their advertising says. You'll have to wade through the manual.

Comment: I was able to mimic the reverb well in LMMS, but the individual volumes of the instruments don't seem to be accurate in this program. Could this have something to do with the normalization base or the gain?

In this example flutes and drums are too quiet:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1121426057690611793/1121426057925500938/LMMS.mp3
It should sound like this:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1121426057690611793/1121426058344923257/INGAME.mp3
I also tried the synthesizer sforzano, but it doesn't make any difference.
In VLC Player, it plays it in the right volume levels.

Comment: Note that the songs in the examples I have removed the reverb completely to show how much the volumes differ even though no effect is used.

Comment: You have to mix it for the playback engine & sample set that's going to be used in the final version. There is no real correlation between sample sets. there's *supposed* to be, but in reality there isn't.