# Set special reverb in midi player/editor which is oriented to midi reverb event

Tags: theory, technique, midi, software, reverb

I am looking for a way to play midis with a special reverb in a midi player or editor.

I'm working on a patch for a videogame which fixes its midi based music (it's buggy in the original game). Among other things, the reverb is completely messed up and needs to be set correctly by hand.

The game uses a globally defined, simple reverb and reads the Midi Command 91 from the songs to set the reverb for the individual channels.
Basically, the command sets a value between dry and wet.

Here is an example. First note has no reverb event, second has one with a value of 70, then 90, 100 and 127:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502388312850300928/1092056255528435742/Reverb.mp3

But in order to adjust the reverb well, I need to recreate this reverb in a midi editor or player so I can hear and adjust the result directly.
But I couldn't find anything like that so far.

With which midi editor or player could you set or mimic this reverb?

With VLC Player, for example, I can configure a reverb with the Spatializer, but this is then fixed to all channels and uses only a single fixed reverb value, instead of that it is oriented to the reverb midi event. I have also experimented with LMMS and could mimick the reverb, but the program seems to use a completely different volume level, causing the volume levels of the individual instruments to be quite different (even if the song doesn't use reverb, LMMS plays the volume levels of the instruments wrong. VLC Player's volumes are correct however).

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Midi CC 91 is not a dry/wet level, it is a send level, completely different thing. You can never achieve 100% wet using that alone, you'd also need to drop the original level separately. Related - https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/129309/mimic-special-midi-reverb-event-that-gets-quieter-the-higher-it-is-set-to

Comment: You're working on a video game and you need certain features for music or sounds? Why not just use one of the free audio middleware packages for video games like FMOD or Wwise?